# php-fpm creats only one socket file

Tags: nginx, virtualhost, php-fpm, socket, ubuntu-20.04

I have multiple virtual hosts with unique domain names, users, and root directories for each on Nginx and php8.1-fpm.

In the `/etc/php/8.1/fpm/pool.d/domain.com.conf` contains

```
user = domainuser
group = domainuser

listen = /var/run/php/php8.1-domain.com-fpm.sock
```

Virtual host file `/etc/nginx/sites-available/domain.com.vhost`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/domain.com;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name domain.com www.domain.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-domain.com-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    access_log /var/log/nginx/domain.com.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/domain.com.error.log;
}
```

When I run `ls -l /var/run/php`, it only shows one socket file, and the other 5 are missing.

```
srw-rw---- 1 www-data www-data 0 Oct 29 12:48 php8.1-domain.com-fpm.sock
```

**Error log:**

```
2023/10/29 12:56:50 [crit] 627#627: *3 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-domain.com-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 20.163.15.11, server: domain.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-domain.com-fpm.sock:", host: "domain.com"
```

Each virtual host has a unique user, group, socket location, and root directory. All users are added to the www-data group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put every site into its own pool, otherwise the config files just override each other.

```
[Site1]
user = domainuser
group = domainuser

listen = /var/run/php/php8.1-domain.com-fpm.sock
```